# Open folder in explorer with vscode has application not found error after changing user folder name

Tags: visual-studio-code, registry

My old user folder name has a problem with other program so I change it by following [answer in superuser (Simon's answer using registry)](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

So I tried to reinstall VS Code but it say cannot create directory that has same name as my old user folder "C:\Users\(old name here)"